# Delete all lines in file that do not match text from another file

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have 2 text files with several lines.
I want to delete all lines in file 1 that doesn't have the text in file 2
example:

file1

```
2345678  sdfsdfsdfsf 10.00 dirfkdkfsdf XP
2345679  sdfsdfsdfsf 10.00 dirfkdkfsdf XP
2345680  sdfsdfsdfsf 10.00 dirfkdkfsdf XP
2345681  sdfsdfsdfsf 10.00 dirfkdkfsdf XP
2345682  sdfsdfsdfsf 10.00 dirfkdkfsdf XP
```

file2

```
2345678
2345679
```

I need to end up with this in file1

```
2345678  sdfsdfsdfsf 10.00 dirfkdkfsdf XP
2345679  sdfsdfsdfsf 10.00 dirfkdkfsdf XP
```

I have to do this in a bash script, using sed, awk, whatever.
I have tried this but doesn't work

Prints all records in file1

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next} !($0 in a)' file2 file1
```

Only prints file2

```
awk 'NR!=FNR{a[$0];next} !($0 in a)' file2 file1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if the files are already sorted by the key, this is the standard solution

```
$ join file1 file2

2345678 sdfsdfsdfsf 10.00 dirfkdkfsdf XP
2345679 sdfsdfsdfsf 10.00 dirfkdkfsdf XP
```

can't get simpler than this.

If you want `awk` solution, this will be it

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next} $1 in a' file2 file1

2345678  sdfsdfsdfsf 10.00 dirfkdkfsdf XP
2345679  sdfsdfsdfsf 10.00 dirfkdkfsdf XP
```

Comment: Hi, awk works great, but if I wanted to catch the match from file2 in the 3 column of file1 instead of the first column ?

Comment: that will be a different question with different input/output.  For join version you have to specify `-j 3` and for `awk` change `$1`s to `$3`

Answer (score 0):

Why `awk`? Use `grep` instead:

```
grep -f file2 file1
```

Comment: I don't think grep is good for this task

Comment: Any arguments against `grep`?

Comment: ok,  E.g. in file1 I have a line: `sdfsdfsdfsf 2345678 10.00 dirfkdkfsdf XP`